# Checkout modification

Tags: product, checkout

Hello i want in checkout page before steps checkout add table with products image, name, total price and quantity, how i can add?

code for display image: `<img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail')->resize(75, 75); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product['name']); ?>" border="0" width="75" />` not working, let me know how i can do this better?

Comment: What is not working? What files are you editing? Any error messages?

Comment: please show  full code the code?i guess that $_product is object of class Mage_Catalog_Model_Product

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a question for you. Is $_product an object or an array? In this code:

```
<img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail')->resize(75, 75); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product['name']); ?>" border="0" width="75" />
```

The first is an object but the second is an array.
Please check it again!